# Python - GIFs not moving and different name assigned when opened via Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I recently started to have fun with Pillow images and wanted to improve my code with some gifs. I have no problem with opening it, but when it does, it's not moving. When I open the gif outside Python, it works normally. I noticed that after gif is opened via Python, it has PNG format and different name (file name is cat.gif, after opening it via code it is tmpin8n7t9z.png). Same applies to JPG pictures - format changed to PNG with different name. I can't see what the issue might be.

```
from PIL import Image

img3 = Image.open('cat.gif')
img3.show()
```

How can I force Python to display opened file a proper name, not just temporary?
How can I force python to display moving gif?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the frames of GIF, the only method that I know is to display all the frames one at a time. It might not be a good solution but it works and I don't know of anything else, check the syntax [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageSequence.html)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

im = Image.open("file.gif")
for i in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
  i.show()
```

This should work, the file name change is because Pillow stores images temporarily with .png extension, for viewing the actual name, why not just store the string, or use the os module, I don't know if there even I a way to do it using Pillow as it is useless, even if there was a way, that would be hard to find.

Comment: Actually I found another way, without using PILLOW. Simpliest way is to do the following:

    `import os
    
    os.system('start cat.gif')`